# SQL inject if statement not accept else

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, select

Running the the following statement, I get an error with if statement in SQL Server 2014:

```
if MAX(A,OS) <> 0 

MAX(A.OS) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento = 'E' THEN Quantidade  ELSE 0 END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento ='S' THEN Quantidade else 0  END)
AS ClosingStock 

else
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento = 'E' THEN Quantidade  ELSE 0 END)
as ClosingStock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you are showing is a part of a SQL statement, I think that you want a `case` *expression* rather than a `if` *statement*. The former is conditional logic that you can use in your query, while the latter is a flow-control structure that comes into play in code blocks, such as stored procedure or the-like:

```
CASE WHEN MAX(A.OS) <> 0 
    THEN MAX(A.OS)
            + SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento = 'E' THEN Quantidade  ELSE 0 END) 
            - SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento ='S' THEN Quantidade else 0  END)
    ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimento = 'E' THEN Quantidade  ELSE 0 END)
END as ClosingStock
```

In SQL Server, you can express the same logic with `IIF()`; I prefer `CASE` because it is standard SQL.

Note that the column alias is declared only once, at the end of the expression.

Also, presumably, `MAX(A,OS)` is meant to be `MAX(A.OS)`.

Comment: Are you sure about `MAX(A,OS)`?

Comment: @Sami: thanks, did not spot that. This is used twice in the query, and the second occurence is `MAX(A.OS)`, so I assume a typo. Added that to my answer.